# Attempt to read from null array-Trying to get Array from other Activity returns null

Tags: java, android, arrays

I got song names using cursor and displayed it in list View in first activity(MainActivity.java). When I click on list View item it redirects to next activity(NextandPrevious.java) and displays the click item in Text View. So far everything is fine. But I have set a next and previous button in second activity.
When I click on next button returns null. The same code works fine if array is assigned with some value in first activity.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
        List<String>Songs=new ArrayList<>();
    int Position,size,take;
   public static final int MY_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=1;
    String[] FavouriteActors;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ShowSongList();




       }



public void ShowSongList(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        }else{ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }else{
        getSongs();
        FavouriteActors=Songs.toArray(new String[Songs.size()]);


        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lists);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,FavouriteActors);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                    Position=i;
                size=listView.getCount();

                String Name=String.valueOf(listView.getItemAtPosition(Position));
                Intent send=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextandPrevious.class);
                send.putExtra("position",Position);
                send.putExtra("value",Name);
                send.putExtra("length",size);
                send.putExtra("array",FavouriteActors[Position]);
                startActivity(send);


            }
        });
    }
}
public void getSongs(){
    try{
        ContentResolver c=getContentResolver();
        Uri uri=MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor cursor=c.query(uri,null,null,null,null);
        if(cursor!=null &&cursor.moveToFirst()){
            int song=cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
            do{
                String SongName=cursor.getString(song);
                Songs.add(SongName);

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }cursor.close();
    }catch (NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch(requestCode){
        case -1:
            //hello
            break;
        case MY_PERMISSION_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if(grantResults.length>0 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ShowSongList();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"You've denied permission",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            break;
        default:
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);}

}


}
```

NextandPrevious.java

```
public class NextandPrevious extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
ImageButton back,next;
    int pos,len;
    String val;
    TextView show;
    String data,nowdata;
    public static int mRequestCode=100;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nextand_previous);
    back=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.back);
    next=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.next);
    show=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    next.setOnClickListener(this);
    Intent get=getIntent();
    pos=get.getExtras().getInt("position");
    val=get.getExtras().getString("value");
    len=get.getExtras().getInt("length");
    nowdata=get.getExtras().getString("array");

    show.setText(String.valueOf(nowdata));

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.back:
            if(pos==0){
               pos=len;
                pos=pos-1;
                MainActivity job=new MainActivity();
                data=job.FavouriteActors[pos];
                show.setText(String.valueOf(data));
            }
            else{
                pos=pos-1;
                MainActivity job=new MainActivity();
                data=job.FavouriteActors[pos];
                show.setText(String.valueOf(data));
            }
            break;
        case R.id.next:
            pos=pos+1;
            MainActivity job=new MainActivity();

            String name=job.FavouriteActors[pos];
            if(name!=null){
                show.setText(name);
            }


            break;
    }
}


}
```

My Error Log is:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.cerebri.droids, PID: 667
              Theme: themes:{com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet=overlay:system, default=overlay:system, iconPack:system, fontPkg:system, com.android.systemui=overlay:system, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:system}
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array
                  at com.example.cerebri.droids.NextandPrevious.onClick(NextandPrevious.java:61)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21158)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Application terminated.
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the mistake.

in MainActivity.java put

```
send.putExtra("array",FavouriteActors);
```

Instead of

```
send.putExtra("array",FavouriteActors[Position]);
```

Coming to NextandPrevious.java change parameter "nowdata" String to StringArray put the below code as

```
String[] nowdata=get.getExtras().getStringArray("array");
```

instead of

```
String nowdata=get.getExtras().getString("array");
```

Finally do the below changes in onClick() method of NextandPrevious.java

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.back:
            if(pos==0){
               pos=len;
                pos=pos-1;
                show.setText(nowdata[pos]);
            }
            else{
                pos=pos-1;

                show.setText(nowdata[pos]);
            }
            break;
        case R.id.next:
            pos=pos+1;
            if(pos>=len){
                pos=0;
            }

           show.setText(nowdata[pos]);



            break;
    }
}
```

Previously I was calling only a string and expecting to return array. Obviously it will throw NPE.

Answer (score 0):

The error is

```
MainActivity job=new MainActivity();
data=job.FavouriteActors[pos];
```

You can't just create a MainActivity Object and expect the Object to have the same data like your previous MainActivity you navigated from. You have to pass the to the NextandPrevious-Activity via Intent like you did with the other variables.

Another tip, learn about java codestyle conventions, variable naming, indention etc. Your Code is really hard to read. Camelcase is the way to go. [StyleGuide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: thank you for your kind reply. I will make a note about your other tip and try to improve.

Comment: You are welcome! If my answer helped you please upvote and mark as accepted. I want to earn some reputation :D.